# sum of rate function in prometheus

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator, prometheus-node-exporter, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

Given the following prometheus time series called **requests** :
[image]

the vector query ***requests[3 seconds]*** is :
[image]

and ***the rate of the vector query requests[3 seconds],  rate(requests[3 sec])*** (computed by the shown formula) is  :

[image]

My question is : what is ***sum(rate(requests[3 sec]))*** evaluated at seconds 5, 4 and 3 respectively is it 16.5, 6.5 and 1. Any idea?

Comment: Prometheus `rate` approximates

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the purpose of sum. It is not performing a sum over time but over the dimensions of your metric.

In your example, assuming there are multiple `requests` metrics (with a dimension `page` by exemple), `rate(requests[3 sec])` will give you (at some point in time):

```
{page="A"}  12.4
{page="B"}  1.5
{page="C"}  0 .... (and so on for each metrics requests with different label set)
```

The `sum` function will sum the values of the different rates; and `sum(rate(requests[3 sec]))` will give you only one value:

```
{}  42.13 <-- the sum of all rate(requests[3s]) values
```

BONUS: In the case you metric have multiple dimensions (represented by multiple labels in your metric) you can tell `sum()` to operate on a subset of them: `sum(rate(requests[3 sec])) ON(foo)`

Comment: @michal did you mean `rate` instead of `ate` in `sum(ate(requests[3 sec])) ON(foo)`

Comment: When I use sum over rate then the value that I see isn't equal to the sum of all the multiple matrices. Would you know why this happens?